# % of SO questions answered as reported on SE sites page

Tags: support, data-explorer

How is the 82% of questions answered for Stack Overflow as listed on [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) calculated?

I thought it would be (Number of posts with an answer) / (Number of posts total)

Number of posts with an answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE AnswerCount >= 1 AND PostTypeId = 1
```

Number posts total:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 1
```

But the answer I received is off by 10% compared to what is displayed. I'm assuming I've misread the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer has to be either upvoted or accepted in order for the question to count as "Answered".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any chance you have the SQL you use to do this?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: I don't have the SQL, but you can get the total unanswered from the API. http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats  (API doc: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help)

Answer (score 1):

This is just to expand on Bill's answer:

NOTE: My understanding is not the sum value of votes, just any answer with at least 1 upvote.

Posts that have at least one answer with an Upvote:

```
WITH posts_with_votes(ID) AS (
   SELECT p.ID
   FROM Posts p
      JOIN Posts aa ON aa.ParentId = p.Id
      JOIN Votes v ON v.PostId = aa.Id
   WHERE aa.PostTypeId = 2
    AND p.PostTypeId = 1
    AND v.VoteTypeId = 2
   GROUP BY p.Id
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_with_votes
```

Result: 884338

Posts that have at least one accepted answer that doesn't fall into the above group:

```
WITH posts_with_votes(ID) AS (
   SELECT p.ID
   FROM Posts p
      JOIN Posts aa ON aa.ParentId = p.Id
      JOIN Votes v ON v.PostId = aa.Id
   WHERE aa.PostTypeId = 2
    AND p.PostTypeId = 1
    AND v.VoteTypeId = 2
   GROUP BY p.Id
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Posts
WHERE AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
    AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM posts_with_votes)
    AND Posts.PostTypeId = 1
```

Result: 98754

884338 + 98754 = 983092

983092 / 1207634 = 81.4%

Apologies for the scrappy SQL.

Comment: Feel free to indicate if this incorrect.. or if you have a nicer way to get this. I just wanted to get the quickest answer to my problem. There's also a limit to what you can do in terms of results and processing time on the Data Explorer, so if you have a better solution it must work using the Data Explorer.

Comment: This is really close to the live numbers from the API and to what's displayed on the site at http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes

Comment: @Bill - Thanks for that. I guess the minor difference in numbers is only due to the data in the data explorer being a few days older.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  The API data is much fresher than the data dump, but not quite as fresh as the site.