# Is SO changing? Zero Upvotes?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I've recently noticed that the, uh, enthusiasm on the site has been a bit... not so strong as before:

[image: zero upvotes]

Does anyone have any guesses as to why this might have happened? Has anything changed recently, and can we do anything about this?

Comment: Click another tab

Comment: @random: I just clicked the "hot" tab and it looks pretty much the same... except now there's also negatives.

Comment: Not exactly a statistically sound sample.  India is not awake yet, Europe has just fallen asleep, America is having dinner. But sure, it's drooping.  Dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/why-are-votes-per-post-on-the-decrease-what-can-we-do-to-improve-this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are referring to the homepage changes, which suppress posts that have upvotes and answers.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: I was like "Ohhhh this must be the reason!!! Thanks!" until I noticed that my `active` tab and my `interesting` tab display the exact same things... both of which are like the one above.

Comment: @mehr sam removed support for that last I checked try in google chrome incognito mode

Comment: @Jeff: Oh what?! I'd complain about that, but instead, here's another observation instead: the `hot` tab is pretty much the same way. :\

Comment: @mehr isn't that a natural consequence of suppressing items from the front page as they have votes and answers? It's all covered in the blog post...

Comment: @Jeff: Huh? Wait I'm a bit confused -- I thought those changes were just for the `interesting` tab, not the other tabs... the `hot` tab's description is `Questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days`, so I assumed that I'd see more votes... but that was hardly the case. :(

Comment: @mehr we explicitly *de* optimize for hotness (or if you prefer, we optimize the homepage for **coldness**), as in, the more answers and upvotes something has, the less likely it is to ever appear on the homepage *at all*. Was the blog post not clear?

Comment: @Jeff: Honestly, no -- all I understood from the blog post was that there was a new tab introduced, and that the old `active` tab was gone, and that it's "personalized" to my taste (which I dislike, btw -- I've turned off every search engine tracking page I've ever come across). Other than that, I didn't expect any difference. But now I guess the question is, why does the `hot` tab say "Questions with the **most** votes" when in fact it's with the *least* votes?

Comment: @mehr I guess I am not being clear, it seems obvious to me. As a *direct* consequence of suppressing hotness on the homepage, daily hotness will inevitably suffer because posts with lots of votes and answers are not simply not seen as much -- the rationale is that we want UNANSWERED questions to get answers, not have people juggle 'what is your favorite programming food?' questions on the homepage all day long. You may wish to switch to the weekly (hot) or monthly (hot) if you are looking for those kinds of things.

Comment: @Jeff: I understand *why* you did that (I'm not confused about that part), but the problem is, the tooltip for the `hot` tab is just misleading: if it's displaying questions with the *least* votes, it shouldn't say the contrary.

Comment: @mehr the hot tab has not changed, there are simply *less hot posts in general* because the homepage actively suppresses hotness. You can compare with SU and SF, because the homepage setting is specific to SO, which is the only site we have that gets 3k questions per day.

Comment: @Jeff: Ohhhhh now I see what you mean by the "less hot posts in general"... yeah okay, now it makes sense. I thought you meant you actively *remove* hot posts (since your answer said "which **suppress** posts that have upvotes", implying that you're not showing something that actually exists), but now [I think] I get what you mean; thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 8):

I can't speak for anyone else, but for me the amount of effort required to sift through the dross and find questions worth voting on, never mind answering, has become too large for me to participate in StackOverflow et al. as much as I used to.

Comment: Are you making good use of the "Ignored tags" and "Prefs -> Hide Ignored tags" features?  I find that this combination helps a lot.  I went through the tags, sorted by popularity, and made a list of a couple hundred tags that I wanted to ignore.

Comment: It's not the dross in uninteresting tags, rather the dross within the tags for which I am qualified to answer - that is, the tag in which I am *interested*.