# Closing questions for certain reasons results in a downvote?

Tags: support, down-votes, vote-to-close, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions closed as “not a real question” and “off topic” get an automatic downvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati)

When I go to close a question **as a moderator** for certain reasons (e.g. `not a real question`, `off-topic`) (not exactly sure which reasons yet), I'll click close, the page refreshes and then shows my name under the question, saying I closed it.  I also noticed that the **question will have a downvote on it**, when **there wasn't one before the page refresh?**

The first couple of times, I thought it was just a freak thing, someone downvoting at the same time as I closed and refreshed the page.  But this has happened a number of times now, so I'm wondering *if this is a new feature* or what?

This is on Super User.

Comment: Most likely you and someone else had the same idea at the same time: "This question sucks."

Comment: I said that @Madmartigan, but this has happened like 8 times now recently...

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automatic

Comment: that must be the [status-complete] result then, @phwd.

Comment: It's a good feature.

Comment: Yip, no penalty for migrations.