# Why do we get random downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I and my friend used to ask programming questions on Stack Overflow, until we saw that 90% of our questions have at least 1 downvote and nobody cares to explain or at least give a clue why.

For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352876/send-mouse-events-to-handle-in-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509317/would-this-kind-of-encryption-be-good-at-anything
- [Start program with a Scheduled Task on startup with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471055/start-program-with-a-scheduled-task-on-startup-with-c)
- [WebMatrix/IIS Express only works with Opera!](https://superuser.com/questions/308327/webmatrix-iis-express-only-works-with-opera)
- [Bootable program to format the internal HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/208706/bootable-program-to-format-the-internal-hdd)
- And many more on Super User... (can't see up/down count there)

It seems to me like you're allowing this kind if mingebag-ish behavior on purpose.
Is it fun to click on a good question's vote count and see like +5/-3? Does it seem right to you?

It definitely doesn't seem right to me or my friend, who quit this website because of this.

Don't you think this must be stopped, possibly now?

You know, my problem here is that, when a question gets a downvote first (has overall negative reputation), it ceases to get views and thus less chances to get an answer.
I came to stack overflow to get answers on my questions, not to have their quality or reason questioned.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352876/send-mouse-events-to-handle-in-c) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509317/would-this-kind-of-encryption-be-good-at-anything) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471055/start-program-with-a-scheduled-task-on-startup-with-c)

Comment: By the way: it's traditional for meta posts complaining about down-voting to be down-voted. It's also traditional for me to shave my head in July and tip my hat at passers-by. Gotta love tradition, eh?

Comment: @Shog9 It's only good for your self-esteem.

Comment: @Vercas: it's also good for keeping your head cool!

Comment: Ask good questions, and it will stop happening.

Comment: Mingebags can't downvote.  You need at least 125 rep for that.

Comment: @Bill Mingebags can get more than 125 rep... :(

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't post this to joke/be joked about. This happens very often and I am quite tired of it.

Comment: RE: *"I CAME TO STACK OVERFLOW TO GET ANSWERS ON MY QUESTIONS, NOT TO HAVE THEIR QUALITY OR REASON QUESTIONED."* That's nice, however Stack Overflow doesn't exist exclusively for your own amusement. Stack Overflow, the community, has downvoted your content, indicating that your content is wrong for this community. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @meagar I am not using SO for my own amusement, I am (have been, from now on) trying to get answers to my questions. I've been seeking help, not criticism. When a question starts with a downvote people start ignoring it, because it *might* be bad. When I post a question, I don't leave, I stay and refresh the page for some time, sometimes for hours, trying to get an answer... And when the first downvote appears, views slow down enormously.

Comment: I don't care whether you came here *seeking* critism, you're going to get it. You don't get to say "nobody can criticize me". Nobody gets to say that. Either adjust yourself to meet the standards of the community, or continue to be rebuked by the community. You are in the wrong here. Fix your attitude and get on with your life.

Comment: Who's joking, @Vercas? I answered your question - if you don't like the answer, I can't really do anything about that. Every question you've given as an example was answered, so I'm not sure what your complaint is here.

Comment: What do you mean by "mingebag" - a n00b, or someone deliberately trying to ruin things?

Comment: @Vercas: But then they're not mingebags any more. They've gained enough rep that they can do stuff. (I assumed by "mingebag" you meant "clueless noob."  Maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: I'd define a mingebag as a "very insistent clueless idiot".

Comment: God's balls man, Stack Overflow is a *programming Q/A site*. We are not a self-help group, or a support therapy group, but some of us *are* very good programmers. I'm not trying to be supportive, I'm trying to tell you how to assimilate into the community, and calling your critics mingebags isn't helping. Ignoring this question and any further @ replies, there is no value in helping one who won't be helped.

Comment: Well, there you go.  Assuming the worst of people who have already proven otherwise rarely ends well.

Comment: I tried to get my questions answered so I can finish my job so I can get something out of it... I didn't ask or complain about my situation. I tried to do it clean. I feel surrounded by blind people. Come on, put your neuron at work. You can't be that stupid to miss the point. -_-

Comment: If anyone happens to figure it out, have a smile. I am out. Too much unwanted attention and I am too mad to think clearly. Just, think about this minge-ish situation, and possible fixes, and think of each consequence, and the consequences of the consequences, etc. You'll find the point. It's hidden right there. I don't want to blow it up. It's just too fun for me to see that nobody has figured it out.

Comment: @Vercas: Whenever you get into the situation where everyone else seems to disagree with you, you might want to consider the possibility that instead of no-one else "getting it", maybe *you're* the one who needs to adjust your thinking.

Comment: @Jon I have considered that, but I keep thinking a Q/A site should help people get their questions answered. That's what I tried to do here, but I can't. And thinking that downvoting a good question is wrong can't be a bad thing. People downvote my questions instead of/without explaining me what's wrong. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @meagar Now that I think more clearly and read your answer again, please answer me this question: Is it wrong to use programming to help myself? I didn't try to hurt anyone, ever. I only tried to help! But I encounter roadblocks in my way and some of them are too heavy for me to move them. I didn't ask anyone to move them for me, but instead I ask for directions around them. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Vercas: The part about wanting explanation for downvotes isn't wrong. What I object to is your "I came to get my questions answered, not to have their quality or reason questioned." I'm not alone in disagreeing with that attitude, but you're still going ahead and insulting anyone who disagrees with you: "I feel surrounded by blind people. Come on, put your neuron at work. You can't be that stupid to miss the point."

Comment: @Jon Ah, damn. I was insulting you. :( I apologize for that. I was very frustrated that nobody at least acted like they see the point.

Comment: This reminds me of the joke about a man who is driving in the wrong side of the highway, and who listen to the radio, "Be careful, there is a man who is driving in the wrong side." He thinks, "I have already found many people driving in the wrong side of the highway."

Comment: You should put more effort into making your questions nice and less into ranting about downvotes on meta. For your second example, you deserve the downvotes for being too lazy to type up your scribbles.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Nice. I stated the point out loud and you still don't get it. **If downvoters would say why they downvoted, I COULD FIX IT.**

Comment: I was referring to what said by @John Skeet: "Whenever you get into the situation where everyone else seems to disagree with you […], maybe you're the one who needs to adjust your thinking." Then, if somebody thinks that your question doesn't show any research, or it is not useful, it is probable you will not get any comment about the down-vote.

Answer (score 19):

> It seems to me like you're allowing this kind if mingebag-ish behavior on purpose.

Yes.

> Is it fun to click on a good question's vote count and see like +5/-3? Does it seem right to you?

I rarely bother checking vote counts on questions unless they're severely overrated. It's not my place to say how anyone else can vote; I cast mine, and go on about my business.

> Don't you think this must be stopped?

No. Let's think about your example: at +5/-3, that question would sit at a +2 rank, which is respectable. The asker would have hopefully gained some useful answers to go along with the +19 reputation points he received for asking. A satisfactory outcome, I would say.

Far more troubling are the questions that don't get voted on at all - up *or* down. Is the asker doing well? Doing poorly? Are these questions useful to anyone else, a credit to the site, or localized eyesores? Hard to say... Which is why I'd rather not see anyone *discouraged* from voting.

Comment: Look at my questions. How many have 0 votes? MOST. So I am doing poorly :P I wouldn't discourage voting, I would encourage thinking before voting.

Comment: @Vercas: I can't know other users' thoughts, or determine how long they agonized over the decision before clicking that button. Voting is fundamentally a personal matter; each reader acts according to his own judgement.

Comment: Concerning your final paragraph: There are just loads of questions which are well-posed and easily answerable, but which are not interesting or relevant at all - anyone with a manual or five minutes on Google could have found out. So definitely no downvote, but also no reason to upvote. (I think that includes 90% of all PHP and MySQL questions ;-).)

Comment: @Kerrek: these may well fall into the "not useful" category; it's hard to be sure at times.

Comment: @Shog9: Well, they're certainly useful to the asker, and often they're perfectly reasonable questions... I've been trying to vote a bit more on questions, but I'm really finding it pretty hard to vote either way most of the time! Down is easier than up, I guess, if you just pile on all those 1-rep-user questions... maybe I'm misunderstanding upvotes, though.

Comment: @Kerrek: the core advice (seen in the little title tips when you hover over the vote buttons) is up == useful, down == not useful. Obviously you don't *have* to vote, but if you do the advice is there. "Useful to the asker" isn't a terribly good reason to bother featuring it / keeping it around though, unless it's useful to someone else.

Comment: @Kerrek I don't mind 0 votes. I am mad about downvote-and-run...

Answer (score 12):

You call the downvotes "random," but I can see a pattern from your sample questions: Two have comments indicating that they are possible duplicates, and one was closed as off-topic. These are all valid reasons for downvotes.

Comment: Was any of them actually duplicate?

Comment: Off topic posts get an [automatic downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automatic).

Comment: @Rick OK. The off-topic did deserve a downvote, or 5 as it has now.