# Off topic automatic down vote is not cast when a migration is rejected because OP is question blocked on target site

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, migration, vote-to-close

The [automatic down vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati) that is cast whenever a post is closed as off topic, is not cast if a migration is rejected because OP is question blocked on the target site, which results in the question closed as off topic on source site.

I'm posting this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since I'd expect the automatic down vote to apply to the eventual state of the question, for the same reasons the automatic down vote exists in the first place. Wouldn't mind making it a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) though...

Comment: I could have sworn I'd already reported this.

Comment: I'm looking at this next - no need for the bounty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downvotes must flow; this will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2012.10.21.4493.