# When questions (or maybe answers) are automatically voted either up or down?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions closed as “not a real question” and “off topic” get an automatic downvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati)

I have many close votes on SO so far. Sometimes (quite less frequently), I have been noticing that as soon as I cast **the last close vote** to a question, the question is closed and it's automatically voted down (again not always).

I don't think that that downvote might have been casted by some user on the site (still I don't know whether it was my illusion or not). I thought it might automatically be done by the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) but I can't find any such mention there.

> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some    attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary    reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

On which criteria, it is done and by whom or it doesn't happen at all? Can I know this?

Comment: That question doesn't explain in which cases an answer is automatically down-voted.

Comment: @kiamlaluno NARQ and OT questions get an automatic downvote (just as the title of the duplicate says)

Comment: @Yannis Rizos - While closing a question even as NARQ or OT, the thing mentioned in the question doesn't seem to happen all the times (if only I ever noticed carefully).

Comment: @Lion I'm a mod on Programmers, and quite a few times I've closed questions unilaterally, the automatic downvote always happens on NARQ and OT closures (one exception was [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126212/off-topic-automatic-down-vote-is-not-cast-when-a-migration-is-rejected-because-o), but it's fixed now).