# Why is Community Moderator ♦ user voting?

Tags: support, voting, moderators

I was going through personal profile of [MSO Community Moderator ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and [SO Community Moderator ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Their personal info written as:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

And this users are not listed in https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all&search=community voters tab.

1. How can background process vote this many times?
2. Is voting being done democratically?
3. Are StackExchange employees handling this accounts?

Comment: The Community user doesn't vote, it only *owns* the votes. If you flag a post for spam it is automatically downvoted, for example, but that downvote is owned by the Community user to make sure you do not loose rep for helping weed out spammers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does this mean my attempts to cozy up to the Community user to get it to serially up-vote me is probably doomed to failure? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I am not divulging the bribery preferences of the Community user; I bought his votes fair and square!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati