# Why are several of my older questions being downvoted at the same time?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

A couple days ago, I noticed that three my questions on Meta Stack Overflow were downvoted around the same time.

Yesterday, [this question on webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/synchronize-mediawiki-redirect-pages) got two downvotes at almost exactly the same time (even though it was a relatively obscure question.)

Additionally, three of my questions on Stack Overflow were downvoted today (apparently at random) within the same hour:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green?tab=reputation

So I'm still not sure why several of my questions (especially older, more-obscure ones) are sometimes downvoted at the same time. Are these random "downvoting sprees" likely to be intentional, or is it more likely to be coincidence?

Comment: Of all of these random downvoting sprees, this one is the most surprising: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/synchronize-mediawiki-redirect-pages It looks like this question got two downvotes at around the same time - perhaps it was on the front page for a short period of time, and attracted a couple of downvotes for that reason.

Comment: Who knows? Votes are anonymous. And with only two downvotes one can't say there is a pattern.

Comment: Especially surprising is the fact that three of my older questions (on Meta Stack Overflow) got downvoted at the same time - this doesn't appear to be entirely coincidental. :/

Comment: Possibly, but there is no way to tell.

Comment: The question you linked is clearly off-topic for the site you posted it on.  I don't know why you are confused about that.  Check their [faq](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: If your question is closed as off topic [it picks up an automatic downvote from community.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati)

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question was about MediaWiki, which is considered a web application (to the best of my knowledge.) In that case, what makes it "off-topic"?

Comment: No, the question is about *programming* MediaWiki.  If you look at the faq, you will see that the site is clearly intended for *users* of web applications, not developers.

Comment: Serial downvoter.If so, the votes will be reversed.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri It looks likely that it was a serial downvoter, but I have no way of knowing who downvoted each question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions get votes when they get views.  Questions get new views for a number of reasons:

1. They get "bumped" to the front page, either by having new activity (edits or new answers posted to them), or by being randomly "poked" by the community user.
2. They show up in a Review Queue.
3. Your user account gets noticed by the community, and they review some or all of your posts.

In all likelihood, your question got more views for the second reason, having appeared in a review queue when the question got closed.

Comment: That's very likely, but it doesn't explain why 3 of my questions on Stack Overflow got downvoted today within a 30-minute time period. This seems much more surprising to me.

Comment: Is there any way to find questions that have been added to the review queue?

Comment: I doubt it; the queues are customized to each user, and probably don't include your own posts, as that would be a conflict of interest.

Comment: Why would the inclusion of my questions in a review queue be considered a conflict of interest?

Comment: Because you would be *reviewing your own posts.*

Comment: In that case, how are the questions customized to each user? If they aren't visible to users, then how can the questions in the queue be reviewed by anyone?

Comment: I don't think you're getting it.  *Your* questions are not visible to *you* but they are visible to *others.*  That's what "customization" means; it means that each person sees a different list of questions in their review queue.

Comment: Are review queues visible to moderators (but not regular users), or are they visible to no one at all?

Comment: I get a review queue just like everyone else.  But my queue has a different list of posts than yours.  Just like everyone else.  Put it this way: I've never seen one of my posts in my own review queue.  Ever.