# "D'oh" type of question

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on SO that seemed very reasonable and folks tried to help & answer. A day later I realized I was doing something dumb, so I immediately added a comment to my question to explain.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236016/issue-installing-ruby-using-homebrew-os-x-lion

Shortly thereafter the question was down voted and closed. What *should* I have done once I realized the problem / fix? I can't delete my question, and down votes just cost me reputation. Kind of perplexed...

Comment: There's an [automatic downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati) if your question gets closed as off-topic. It's only 2 rep though; not a _huge_ deal.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati. And in case of a d'oh question, I would usually vote to close it as "too localized".

Comment: Why can't you delete your question? It doesn't have any upvoted answers.

Comment: @MartinSmith: 0 score answers prevent deletion as well. Otherwise one could post a question, get an answer, and delete immediately before votes come in.

Comment: @Manishearth didn't realise that was the rule. Will it still get deleted by the auto cleanup script with a zero score answer?

Comment: @MartinSmith: yep http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/178438

Comment: @Manishearth Though there is nothing stopping you downvoting the answer then deleting the question.

Comment: @Manishearth [This question with an unupvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483320/teaching-worker-to-accept-code-instead-of-javascript-source-file) was successfully deleted by the OP, a day after posting the question (May '12). I believe that questions without upvoted answers can still be deleted.

Comment: @RobW: i think there's a delay then. Not sure, but IIRC there are checks in place to prevent a user from self-deleting once they have answers.

Comment: @Manishearth As far as I know, one cannot delete one's question if a) it has an upvoted (positive score, I think) answer, or b) it has multiple answers. One unupvoted (score `<= 0`, methinks) answer allows the OP to delete the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most d'oh questions are "too localized" (though "off topic" works as well since it's more of a universal close reason). The downvote was automatic.

You can't delete it yourself because it has a non-negative scored answer.  I would just forget about it and move on. -2 rep isn't much in the grand scheme of things.

---

In general, when you solve your own non-close-worthy question, post it as an answer -- answering your own question is perfectly acceptable. In this case, your question was a localized issue, so no need to do that.

Comment: I can move on, no problem. It's not the -2 rep, I just was curious what the intended behaviour in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeCapka This is the intended behavior.  Once a question is closed as 'too localized' it's eligible for deletion, so you can flag it for a moderator to clean up.