# Any insight on why this question was closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

**Question:** [Why is the SSMS GUI so slow and what can I do to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815313/why-is-the-ssms-gui-so-slow-and-what-can-i-do-to-fix-it)

The question linked above received 2 close votes, I asked for comments regarding the issue and this morning I've found it's been voted to close and even received a down vote.  Nice!

I understand how this community works and I'm not afraid of criticism.  What I don't like is when people close questions without even giving an excuse.  If my question isn't appropriate for one reason, or another, I'm fine with that.  However, I'd like some form of comment regarding the problem with my question.

Can someone with some form of admin credentials please let me know what was wrong with my question?  Also, what can I do to re-ask it in such a way that I'm not breaking any rules?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Well, though the question is about a software tool, you are asking why it is slow for you. You have ruled out hardware but there is no way to find out why the tool is slow for you. I'd say this is not answerable, so got closed.

Comment: To add on @Oded correct point, I'd say that this question is on topic on the product's forums and not Stack Overflow. If you would have query that is running slow, or something more related to programming, then it would be on topic.

Comment: SO is for languages, not for hardwares.

Comment: Also worth to mention the downvote is automatic as result of the question being closed as off topic, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84978/152859). No human finger clicked the downvote arrow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **NARQ**

Not a real question.

As Oded mentioned, you ruled out hardware, so you are asking what's wrong with software. In a way, the question should have been migrated to SU - it seems like it would have been a better fit there than anywhere else.

Comment: That's what I assumed but since this is related to DB software, I didn't want to post it on SU, only to have it moved to DBA and then have DBA close the question.  I've seen this happen to other's questions and it has even happened to me once before.  I think the question is certainly legitimate.  I just had a tough time discerning the right place to put it.  I think I'll delete my question and re-ask it over at SU.  Thank you.

Comment: @RLH You could flag it an ask a mod to migrate it - that would save you the difficult task of copying and pasting :)

Comment: Thanks undo, that's actually what I did.

Answer (score 2):

When people vote to close they choose a reason. (This might be the "excuse" you want them to provide.) If you click the Close link you can see what reasons have been chosen so far, and then Cancel so you don't actually vote to close.

If 5 votes accumulate the question is closed and you will see the majority close reason at the bottom of the question. If you edit the question to fix the problem, it can be re-opened. Some problems (such as being off topic) are nearly impossible to fix, however.

Sometimes people leave comments explaining their vote-to-close motivation and offering suggestions for improving your question or getting it reopened. **They are under no obligation to do so.** Same with downvotes. Commenting is optional. You can't come here and demand people give you "excuses" for their choices. The system works well to get bad things fixed up even if that isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: There may be no obligation for people to give an excuse for their actions, but IMHO, when an asker asks for help on how to fix a problematic question, common courtesy should dictate responding with helpful comments.  The point of this site isn't to have a perfectly maintained, pretty Q&A site.  It's to help people get answers to their questions within the parameters of a few specific rules.  If you aren't sure if you are acting within the bounds of what's correct, those who critic should also constructively advice.

Comment: I don't want to go back and forth, but I don't want to just ignore you either. The people who close and edit questions can get tired. There is a never ending supply. Some days they feel their obligation to the site (keep it clean) more strongly than they feel their obligation to the people who are not using the site correctly (help them understand how it works.) My point is the two obligations are independent. Some people only comment on how to improve but never edit or vote to close. Some other way round. Both are just fine and **not deficient**, not something to fix.

Comment: No back-and-forth necessary and I do understand your point.  I, for one, am a HUGE supporter of this site because I think it has an amazing community! However, I have a lot of responsibilities and it has just been frustrating from time-to-time to see these types of things happen and not have a clear understanding on how to improve the situation. Still, thanks for your insight. It certainly provides some clarity to the broader context.